# How do I get my navigation button to be inline?

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a sign out button in my navigation menu, but it is not staying properly inline, it's slightly off, here is my code.

HTML:

```
<nav class="col-sm-3" style:"height:20vh;!important">
  <a href="../Pages/account.php" id="navigation">Account</a>
  <a href="../Pages/chat.php" id="navigation">Chat</a>
  <a href="../Pages/video_chat.php" id="navigation">Video Chat</a>
  <form action="../Universals/signout.php" id="navigation_form">
    <button>Sign Out</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

CSS for the Links:

```
#navigation a {
 white-space: nowrap!important;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 25px 20px 15px;
 min-width: 140px;
 padding: 1px!important;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black!important;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer!important;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: right!important;
 align-items: right!important;
}
```

CSS for the Form:

```
#navigation_form {
 white-space: nowrap!important;
 display: inline;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin: 25px 20px 15px;
 min-width: 140px;
 padding: 1px!important;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white!important;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer!important;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center!important;
 align-items: center!important;
```

### }

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

Comment: `display: inline-block;` or `display: table/table-cell;` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
form {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Ok, then try removing the `margin: 25px 20px 15px;` from the #navigation_form element. Now it should display at the same spacing as the rest

Comment: changing it to margin: 10px 20px 15px; worked for me at display:flex; thanks!